# Using backslash-newline sequence in Tcl

Tags: tcl, newline, substitution, backslash

In Tcl, we are using the backslash for escaping special characters as well as for spreading long commands across multiple lines.

For example, a typical `if` loop can be written as

```
set some_Variable_here  1
if { $some_Variable_here == 1 } { 
    puts "it is equal to 1"
} else { 
    puts "it is not equal to 1"
}
```

With the help of backslash, it can be written as follows too

```
set some_Variable_here  1
if { $some_Variable_here == 1 } \
{ 
    puts "it is equal to 1"
} \
else { 
    puts "it is not equal to 1"
}
```

So, with backslash we can make the statements to be treated as if like they are in the same line.

Lets consider the `set` statement

I can write something like as below

```
set x Albert\ Einstein;# This works
puts $x

#This one is not working
set y Albert\
Einstein
```

If I try with double quotes or braces, then the above one will work.  So, is it possible to escape the newline with backslashes without double quotes or braces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A backslash-newline-whitespace* sequence (i.e., following whitespace is skipped over) is always replaced with a single space. To get a backslash followed by a newline in the resulting string, use `\\` followed by `\n` instead.

```
set y Albert\\\nEinstein
```